# Editable custom field WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I created a custom field on WooCommerce, but the field is not editable from the backend, and when I insert the manual orders I cannot fill it out. how should I correct it?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );


function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

   return $fields;
}


    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'bbloomer_shipping_phone_checkout_display' );

function bbloomer_shipping_phone_checkout_display( $order ){
    echo '<p><b>Telefono per consegna:</b> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_phone', true ) . '</p>';
}
```